# flatten keyless json to csv format using jq

Tags: json, export-to-csv, jq

How can I flatten the following json into csv format? The problem I am facing is that this json contains values in places of keys, and all the examples and tutorials that I have seen show how to handle json with keys and values. So I am not even sure where to begin.

JSON: This is what I currently have

```
{
  "AE": {
    "424,2": "Etisalat",
    "424,3": "DU"
  },
  "AF": {
    "412,50": "Etisalat"
  }
}
```

CSV: This is what I would like to have as output

```
"AE","424,2","Etisalat"
"AE","424,3","DU"
"AF","412,50","Etisalat"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
paths(scalars) as $p | $p + [getpath($p)] | @csv
```

`paths(scalars)` finds paths to non-iterable values and lists them as arrays (e.g `["AE","424,4"]`),
`getpath($p)` returns the value at path represented by `$p`.

Note that `-r/--raw-output` option is required for proper CSV output.